# ArcGIS Android SDK Calculate area in square meters from polygon geometry?

Tags: geometry, area, arcgis-android

I have a Polygon object in ArcGIS Android SDK that I'm creating on a map, I would like to calculate that polygon object to square meters.

currently I use

```
 double area=polygon.calculateArea2D();
```

But I don't know what that geometry's default unit is to convert from..

Anyone know how I can take that Geometry's area and convert to meters squared?

Answer (score 2):

[MapView.getSpatialReference().getUnit()](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgismobile/10.0/apis/android/api/com/esri/core/geometry/SpatialReference.html#getUnit%28%29) returns the units of the MapView, which the polygon on the map inherits. You can write a switch statement to handle the conversion to meters from the various units, or perhaps the [GeometryEngine.project](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/android-sdk/api/com/esri/core/geometry/GeometryEngine.html#project%28com.esri.core.geometry.Geometry,%20com.esri.core.geometry.SpatialReference,%20com.esri.core.geometry.SpatialReference%29) method will help.